# How to use environment variable declared in /etc/profie into script running through monit?

Tags: shell, rhel, monit

Environment variable declared in /etc/profile:

```
export MYNAME=rhel
```

Content of script which is running from monit is [/tmp/printmyname.sh]:

```
echo "My Name is: "$MYNAME >> /var/log/env_variablefile.out
```

Content of monit:

```
check file PrintVariable with path /var/log/something.out
   start program = "/bin/sh /tmp/printmyname.sh"
   if timestamp > 1 minutes then start
```

I want to print environment variable declared in `/etc/profile` to `/var/log/env_variablefile.out` when `/var/log/something.out` file is not updated since one minute.

So my problem is when i directly run `/tmp/printmyname.sh` it append `My Name is: rhel` into `/var/log/env_variablefile.out` but when it is running from monit it only prints `My Name is:`.

So I want to know the reason of such behavior and a way to solve problem.

Note: monit is running every 10Seconds and above code is just example of my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/profile` is only executed for interactive shells.

One way to fix this is to add this to the beginning of `/tmp/printmyname.sh`:

```
. /etc/profile
```

Note that this may cause problems because `/etc/profile` tries to set up an interactive environment, so a lot of setup scripts will be called that you may not want.

A better solution is probably to put this variable in a new global script and source this new script from both `/etc/profile` and `/tmp/printmyname.sh`

Related articles:

- [Execution sequence for .bash_profile, .bashrc, .bash_login, .profile and .bash_logout](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/)
- [Bash and Its Startup File Execution Algorithm](http://savage.net.au/Linux/html/bash.files.html)
- [/etc/profile not being sourced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40287/etc-profile-not-being-sourced)